# Check in a method if the parameter equals a specific method

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, parameters

I use the code line:

```
MethodBase senderMethod = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
```

inside a method to get the information of the method's identity.
I then invoke another method using the senderMethod  as argument in the method call:

```
RefreshLineSelection(_cursorLocation, senderMethod);
```

In the method RefreshLineSelection I need to check the identity of the calling method, as this method is invoked from two different methods.
I do this thus:

```
                string name = senderMethod.Name;
                if (name == "Panel_MouseMove")
                {
                }
```

It seems to me that there should be a more elegant way.
I tried:

```
if (senderMethod == Panel_MouseMove)
{
}
```

and also:

```
if (senderMethod.Equals(Panel_MouseMove))
{
}
```

but I get error messages I do not know how to resolve.

In one sentence, my question is: What is the correct syntax for:

```
if (senderMethod.Equals(Panel_MouseMove)) 
{ 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not pass the name of the calling method as a string or a custom enum?

Comment: @madreflection I could do that really, it is a good idea. I would like to know though how to check inside the method in the way I did it till now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use CallerMemberName-attribute to automatically inject a method name as a parameter, and the nameof operator to get the name of a method. But I think you should describe the actual goal you are trying to accomplish better.

Comment: @
JonasH Tha actual goal is to learn what I am doing wrong in the statements I showed! What is the correct syntax for: if (senderMethod.Equals(Panel_MouseMove))
{
}

Comment: Are you looking for the `nameof` operator perhaps? `if (senderMethod.Name == nameof(Panel_MouseMove)`? Or you could fetch the `MethodInfo` you expect, statically and store it. Having said that, I would *strongly* advise against this as a design approach anyway. It would really make more sense to have a parameter indicating the desired difference in behavior.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thank you for the advice and the correct form. I really looked for the syntax: if (senderMethod.Name == nameof(Panel_MouseMove)

Comment: If you want to use `if (senderMethod == Panel_MouseMove)`, you need to declare `Panel_MouseMove` as `MethodBase` and assign it the object that represents that method. If `Panel_MouseMove` *is* the method, you need a separate variable for the test.